# Displaying frames in an applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jpanel

I am writing a Java Swing Application. It consists of a graphing tool which I added as a library. It works fine as a desktop application. However, I'm trying to convert this application into an applet and the graphing frame won't come up on the browser. The code for the invoking the graphing frame is:

```
double x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
double y[] = {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0};        
plot.addLinePlot("plot", Color.BLUE, x, y);    
JFrame frame = new JFrame("A Plot Panel");
frame.setSize(1400, 730);
frame.setContentPane(plot);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I typed the same lines in the applet but it won't work in the browser.
How do I make this work in an applet?

Comment: My monitor is only 1366 wide. Am I excluded from seeing the entire frame?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441654/2587435), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2435305/2587435) see if they help.

Comment: @peeskillet thats just a case scenario

Comment: @AndrewThompson to make it available for over a network

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps. (e.g. based on `JFrame`) over a network, the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 1):

extend the `Applet` class, add all your gui elements accordingly, you can not show a frame in a browser applet is provided as a main container as `Frame` or `JFrame` in desktop application.

example:-

```
    public class MyApplet extends Applet{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
            /* Your applet code here
               */
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawRect(20,20,200,180);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all you gui elements in a panel and add to applet/frame as appropriate